# Item setting in django model / class

Tags: python, django

What would be the best way to have a custom setter for a field that needs to be saved to the DB? For example:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    episode_number = models.IntegerField()
    season_number = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='Alula')
    episode_and_season_number # str(self.season_number) + str(self.episode_number).zfill(2)
```

While it can be a property for reading purposes:

```
    @property
    def episode_and_season_number(self):
        str(self.season_number) + str(self.episode_number).zfill(2)
```

I need to save that value to the database. What would be the suggested way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create it as a CharField then populate it in the save method.

```
class Item(models.Model, ItemMixin):
    episode_number = models.IntegerField()
    season_number = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='Alula')
    episode_and_season_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.episode_and_season_number  = str(self.season_number) + str(self.episode_number).zfill(2)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: yes, that's what I'm currently doing, but was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to do this (also you'd want to call the `save` after setting the value).